# Youtube Player API: Play private videos with access_token

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I performed oAuth to access private videos from youtube API.

I'm able to play the videos with URL: www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoId}&access_token={access_token}

But I'm unable to find out how to add the access token in the Youtube Player API (Javascript).

Below is the code I'm using to load the youtube player, I've tried to add access_token I got from User OAuth in 2 places as shown in the code, but none works.

```
new YT.Player("youtube-placeholder", {
                videoId: this.videoId,
                access_token: this.access_token,
                playerVars: {
                    // "access_token": this.access_token,
                    "controls": 0,
                    "cc_load_policy": 0,
                    "iv_load_policy": 3,
                    "rel": 0,
                    "disablekb": 1,
                    "enablejsapi": 1,
                    "fs": 0,
                    "modestbranding": 1,
                    "playsinline": 1
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': this.initTimes.bind(this),
                    'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)
                }
            });
```

Can someone please let me know how to do it, if at all possible.

Thank you,

Comment: Please update your post to include the code where you are calling the API if you would like assistance with adding the token.

Comment: I've included the code, but haven't received a reply in a while. Does anyone know how to achieve this, if at all possible?

Comment: Try `videoId:this.videoId + "&access_token:" + this.access_token` it may works.

Comment: Found any solution?